# .Net Core Hangfire Jobs Status Serilog Logging

Tags: c#, .net-core, logging, serilog, hangfire

I am wondering if there is a nuget or a way to automatically log hangfire job status.

For example:

`[Timestamp] [JobName]-[JobId] has started with parameters [parameters]`

or

`[Timestamp] [JobName]-[JobId] has finished with status [status] and returned [returnObject]`

I am using .net core 5 and serilog.

Comment: Take a look at their docs. https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/extensibility/using-job-filters.html